# javascript: async / await – propagation required the entire call chain up?

Tags: node.js, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I am wrapping a function returning a promises into an `async` function on a small helper function...

```
trash(filesArray, {
    glob: false
})
.then(() => {
    resolve(true);
}).catch((err) =>  {
    return err;
})
```

…because I like to use it synchronous using the `await` on the next-higher level:

```
async empty(liveMode, force) {
    …
    await helpers.trashSync(trashFiles);
    // then doing further stuff...
}
```

Of course, this means, that I need to use the `async` keyword again... (otherwise I am told `await` is an ‘unknown reserved’ word or such) and if I am not mistaken, I will now need to use `await` again on the next-higher level?

```
await memberSet.empty(true, false)
```

**Does this “game” continue all the way up and throughout my application, so by the end, I have plenty of `async`/`await`'s wherever there's a tiny async function contained?**

**Or am I simply missing the point where to stop?**

Comment: "*I like to use it synchronous*" - that's not possible. An asynchronous function always finishes in the future. "*using the await*" just makes your function asynchronous, i.e. returning a promise that resolves in the future after something has been awaited.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45448272/1048572).

Comment: Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35380162/is-it-ok-to-use-async-await-almost-everywhere)

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert an async function into a sync function, the purpose of async/await is to allow you to write code that has a similar code path to synchronous calls, but allowing the event loop to be re-entrant and therefore more fine grained.  Generator/yield is an alternative approach to interrupting flow of execution.

You'll need to find a point where your call stack naturally expects a returned promise, or doesn't care that it completes asynchronously.