# How to make this code synchronous by blocking the execution thread?

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of code with an API call in the topmost JS import which I need to use everywhere else in the project.
How to make this asynchronous?

My HTML file looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="header"></h1>

    <script src="src/script1.js"></script>
    <script src="src/script2.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

First JS file:

```
const fetchData= async () => {
    const configUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';

    try {
        const response = await fetch(configUrl);

        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`Network response was not ok: ${response.status} - ${response.statusText}`);
        }

        const res = await response.json();
        console.log('data 0:',res)
        return data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    }
};

window.data = fetchData();

console.log("data 1:",data);
```

Second JS file:

```
console.log("data 2:",window.data)
```

Basically I want window.data with the data from the endpoint to be accessible everywhere. I want to continue the program execution only after the api call is done. That is, the thread should be blocked for the API call and rest of the program (js files) should execute only after the api call.
Im not ready to move other JS file code to first 1 nor import it inside first using @import in .then block of first.

Is there any clean approach for this?

Live example: https://playcode.io/1696111

In the example I want console.log inside script2.js to print the API data.

Comment: _"How to make this code synchronous"_, _"How to make this asynchronous?"_ - Which do you mean? You don't want to block the thread as this will make your app unresponsive.

Comment: *"the thread should be blocked for the API call"*: ouch, that would be really, really bad. It should be avoided at all costs. In JavaScript you never want to block the thread. It is bad practice.

Comment: You could do `const data = await window.data` in your second file to "wait" for the data to come through. Note that this can only be done in async context. So you need to be inside an `async function`. Otherwise you have to use `window.data.then((data) => { ... })`.

Comment: to wait for an async function to fullfill the promise before returning, requires `await`as stated above.. but also blocking the UI thread will freeze the UX and that's considered very bad.

Comment: A solution will be to only add `script2.js` after the `Promise` was fulfilled, something like `fetchData().then((data) => {
  window.data = data;
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = 'src/script2.js';
  document.head.append(script);
});`

Comment: By the way, `fetchData` returns `data` (which doesn't exist), it should probably return `res`.

Comment: "*an API call [whose result] I need to use everywhere else in the project.*" - just don't make the rest of the project a top-level script relying on global variables. [Put it in functions and pass the data as an argument!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35380604/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi Can you ellobarate this with an example? I want the data of that api to my app to be functional. Basically that api has collection of apis that I need to call in various places in the app

Comment: @Noel Can you elaborate on what your *script2.js* is actually doing (rather than just logging the data)? Also what does "*that api has collection of apis that I need to call in various places*" mean? It would be helpful if you could show some of your actual code.

Comment: Just for completeness - there [is a way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest_API/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#synchronous_request) to do literally what you asked for, but for the love of everything holy, please don't use it. (There are only extremely rare and obscure cases in which I ever had to use that - cases you probably won't encounter at all when you are a beginner or intermediate-level developer. 99.9% of the time there is a better way.)

Comment: @CherryDT I was waiting for this answer. This will indeed solve the problem but its an anti-pattern.I think I should re consider the way in which my app is architected. Just to elaborate, what Im currently doing is calling an API that returns an object of all the APIS to be used across the app. I have done this way because it will be easier to switch between production, dev and staging in this case. Is there any better way that you would recommend to handle this scenario better?

Comment: @Agent047 One way would be to put that configuration of API URLs not in a `fetch` call, but use a (synchronous) jsonp script or even inline `<script>` that initialises some global constants. But if those API URLs are only used in API calls that are asynchronous themselves, just keep the promise for configuration and wait for it in every API call method: ``const urlsPromise = fetchData('/urls'); … async function fetchX(id) { return fetchData(`${(await urlsPromise).endpointX}/${id}`); }``

Comment: @Bergi Hmm..You point one seem to be a clean and good idea that I can implement without much of a code change. The second one seem to be not possible in my context as it would require a larger change.

Answer (score 2):

You can't`*` block the main thread, but you can defer loading other scripts until the data is received:

```
function loadScript(url) {
   // for example,
   let script = document.createElement('script');
   script.type = 'text/javascript';
   script.src = url;
   document.body.appendChild(script)
}

fetchData().then(_ => loadScript(script2))
```

`*` By saying "can't" I mean "while you technically might be able to, browser vendors put a lot of effort into preventing you from doing so and it would be unwise to go against them".

Comment: Hmm this looks good but my project has around 30 scripts so Im afraid this would make the code worse.

Comment: @Noel:  in this case, I would seriously consider restructuring your application, as suggested in the comments: wrap each script in a function and call these functions with the `data` argument when appropriate.

Comment: Just to clarify. My use case is to consume all the endpoint used across the app initially from an endpoint. Any reason why this is considered a bad practise? Is it due to the fact that the entire app functions based on this single endpoint or it increases the loading time?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using an `await import("...")` to load an index of all the dependent modules?

The script1 would be

```
// src/script1.js

const fetchData= async () => {
    const configUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';

    try {
        // ...
        return data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    }
};

(async (index) => {
    window.data = await fetchData();
    console.log("data 1:",data);
    try {
        // import the index file after the data arrives
        await import(index)
    } catch (e){
        console.log("error importing", e)
    }
})("./index.js")
```

Then you could make a js index module like the following

```
// src/index.js

export * from "./script2.js"
// more import/export ...
```

And in the index.html you have to remove all the script other than the script1.js.

Unfortunately the `await import(index)` doesn't work on https://playcode.io/1696111 so you have to find another way around to play with  this, like `python3 -m http.server` in your local folder, then opening the console of the browser you should see

```
data 0: {userId: 1, id: 1, title: 'delectus aut autem', completed: false}
data 1: {userId: 1, id: 1, title: 'delectus aut autem', completed: false}
data 2: {userId: 1, id: 1, title: 'delectus aut autem', completed: false}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Vue SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9kctOwzAQRX/F8iaJVIVCd31JgLqABVTQZTZWMhSX+CF73BRV/XfG7lOi6s6+547mzsyWP1pbrgPwIR/72kmLzAMGO620VNY4ZFl5twf35cpno//6w0EfH/5USh8EZVuBQD/GIrwQeI+jr43+kkuqNZqab5ON10ZZ2YJ7tyiN9hUfskQiE21rutekoQvQO+r1N9Q/V/SV30St4nMHHtwaKn5iKNwScI9nn2+wofcJKtOEltw34Ad404aYcW97Crqh2Be+lPYlrUrq5cLPNgjaH4eKQaNzl/wVpws83xj9HHdQDlJdpXe0xfNhaIWd1I3pykagYBOmoWNzZ5T0kNP8pl0Dm0zjcRdSgQmY50UUDizP1C+LpVnRY4N+v18Uo1ODeGFqICgd5kx0QiK77EbW3R92OMCK)

Just add `type="module"` to your scripts
and use `console.log("data 2:", await window.data)`

Comment: `await window.data` is rather confusing. I think a better way would be to set `window.data = await fetchData()`.

Comment: @CherryDT that wouldnt work

Comment: Well, [for me it does](https://replit.com/@CherryDT/SO77665739#src/script1.js). Click "DevTools" to see the output. (I had to change `res` to `data` within the `fetchData` function though, probably some kind of copy&paste error by OP.)

Comment: @CherryDT this is completely different setup from the OP's, when script2 imports script1. in the OP's setup script2 knows nothing about script1 and interacts only with `window.data`

Comment: I just simplified things, you can achieve the same result by having a third file simply import both other files (in order). Then script2 has to know even _less_ about script1 because it doesn't have to await anything either.

Comment: @CherryDT you can either `await` either in script1 or script2, right

Comment: @CherryDT it's all depends on the OP's intention. if the script1 should continue without waiting `fetch()` than `await` should be in script2. using `await` in the both scripts doesn't hurt either

Comment: Thanks for the input @CherryDT and Alexander Nenashev . Unfortunately this is not the kind of solution I was looking for. My intention is to make the data available intially without awaiting inside each of the calls. This is because it will require lot of code change in that case and not all scripts I can make the change